# Conversion of int[] to byte[] with 1 int corresponding to 1 byte

Tags: c#, type-conversion, int, byte

i am using `Stream.Write(byte[],int int)` function to write to a stream but i am unable to convert my `int[] to byte[]` , in my integer array I have 56 integers and all of them are under 8 bit value. I want to convert my int []  byte[] in such a way that my byte[] also has 56 bytes.

Like this

> int[]= {0x0004,0x0001,0x0003,0x0003}
>    byte[] ={ 0x04,0x01,0x03,0x03}

Thanks in Advance

Comment: A [mcve] would be great.

Comment: And what would you want to convert `0xffff` or `0x0100` to as they are larger values than a single byte can store?

Comment: @JordiJordi the answer you referred to says "If you want a bitwise copy, i.e. get 4 bytes out of one int". OP wants to get one byte per every int.

Comment: @DavidG OP says "all of them are under 8 bit value"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to extract the low byte from every int: `myByte = (byte)(myInt & 0xFF)`

```cs
using System.Linq;
//...
int[] integers = {0x0004,0x0001,0x0003,0x0003};
byte[] bytes = integers.Select(n => (byte)(n & 0xFF)).ToArray();
```